Embed youtube video as the background video in html page covering entire viewport
I am making a landing page where video will be autoplay as background video. I uploaded my video to youtube and embedded the link like this:
<section class="relative pt-16">
    <iframe
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/h9tTK0LbXfE?autoplay=1&mute=1&loop=1&controls=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&rel=0"
            frameborder="0"
            allow="autoplay"
            allowfullscreen
            class="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full object-cover"
    ></iframe>

The video is embedded but problem is it;s not covering entire viewport while my code seems to to that. Maybe I am doing something wrong. Notice my output it's not covering entire viewport:
my code output image
Help me figuring out what is mistaken.

[edit] your question and add your CSS code.
